# Do I have to manually delete object even after destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

This question relates to C++ game engine, called AppGameKit (AGK).

I've created a separate class for Text so that I don't have to call AGK functions when creating Text. Here's the simple class:

**Text.h**

```
class Text 
{
  private: int _ID;
  void Destory();

  public:
    void AddText();
  Text(int ID);
  ~Text();
};

Text::Destroy() 
{
  agk::DeleteText(_ID);
}

Text::~Text() 
{
  Text::Destroy();
}
```

Now my question is when I'm calling this class in any other class, say MainMenu, do I have to delete the button in the class MainMenu that I'm creating using this class or will the destructor of Text will automatically get called and delete the button.

**MainMenu.cpp**

```
MainMenu::Initilization()
{
        Text * mainText = new Text(1);
}

MainMenu::Destory()
{
       agk::DeleteText(1); // DO I HAVE TO DO THIS?
}

MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
       MainMenu::Destory(); 
}
```

AGK function delete is called to delete text so that the memory is deallocated. Similar to C++ delete keyword.

Personally, I think deleting the button in MainMenu class should be unnecessary but I'm confused as to whether the destructor of Text class is even called. Please let me know if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: Since you don't `delete` `mainText` the destructor won't be called at all. Actually, since `mainText` is a local variable inside the `Initilization` function, if you don't save the pointer somewhere else so you can `delete` it you will have a memory leak.

Comment: If you don't want to call delete you should use std::unique_ptr or one of the other smart pointers. Always remember RAII.

Comment: You shouldn't really have a method called `Destroy().` All that should be in the destructor, where people will expect to find it, and where it can't be called by accident.

Comment: @HaukeS This should be the accepted answer to every one of these questions at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Every** `new` has to be balanced with a `delete` else you *will* leak memory. (You can use classes like `std::unique_ptr` which will manage the deletion for you but they still call `delete` under the hood).

Currently, `mainText` goes out of scope at the end of the `Initilization` function, so you lose the pointer that you need for a successful `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to manually delete object even after destructor?

No.

---

You called `Text * mainText = new Text(1);` in `Initialization`, so call `delete mainText` in `Destroy`

When you call `delete mainText`

- If `mainText` is not null its destructor would be called
- If `mainText` is not null its memory would be freed

No need to mention, the destructor already calls `agk::DeleteText`

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule of thumb in C++ is for every new() there must be a delete(). This ensures that there would be no memory leakage.
In most modern OS, there is no memory leakage ever. Once your program exits, the OS claims back the memory and puts it back in heap.
But what happens when your program is running for a long time. This means you will keep leaking memory until your program exits.
So it's best to delete the allocated memory and adhere to the rule of thumb.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is plain wrong. Sure, when the process terminates the OS will reclaim the memory, but while it's running it still leaks memory, i.e. "using" memory for no reason, filling it with inaccessible data in case of pointers..

Comment: @crembo : please read the last part of my answer carefully.Dnt u think I said the exact same thing. Read and decide!!! and thn downvote